# NHibernate DateTime millisecond precision

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, nhibernate, timestamp

I am having trouble with millisecond precision using NHibernate with Mysql, in my C# application.

I want to store a `DateTime` variable in a Mysql database using Nhibernate.
I have created a date column using the following:

`Date DATETIME(6) NOT NULL`

NHibernate's documentation has the following mapping for the column:

`<property name="Date" column="Date" type="Timestamp"/>`

Using `type="Timestamp"` should give me what I require, however I keep losing the millisecond precision

Values in database for the Date column look like this:

```
'2014-06-17 19:58:58.000000'
'2014-06-17 19:58:58.000000'
'2014-06-17 19:58:59.000000'
'2014-06-17 19:58:59.000000'
```

Nhibernate document type mapping:

```
Timestamp   System.DateTime DbType.DateTime
```

as specific as database supports. `type="Timestamp"` must be specified.

*Note*: I have seen some similar posts for Oracle and SQL server but the solution to use 
`type="Timestamp"` does not seem to work for me.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Prior to 5.6.4, it didn't offer subsection time precision.

Comment: The version I have is 5.6.17 on AWS

Comment: I have found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have identified the problem, when I installed MySQL something happened and the c# connection tools did not install correctly. Once Uninstalled Mysql connect for C# and resinstalled it, updated the project references and it worked.